# Mostrar muchos numeros en un TextField con JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Muy buenas tengo un problema y es que tengo un ejercicio que se basa en mostrar en un textArea los N primeros numeros primos. El numero N lo pido en un TextField. Y al darle al boton calcular me muestra en el textArea los N primeros numeros primos. El problema es que me muestra solamente el ultimo elemento, no me muestra los anteriores. Os dejo aqui el codigo(el codigo es funcional).

Necesito que me digan como puedo mostrar varios numeros usando una funcion lambda y sin tener que almacenarlos en un vector o lista ni nada por el estilo. Un saludo.

```
package ejerciciosJavaFx;

import java.util.Vector;

/*
 * @author Tomás Hidalgo
 * 
 * Mostrar en pantalla los N primeros numeros primos. 
 * Se pide la cantidad de numeros primos a mostrar.
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ejPrimos extends Application{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage escenario) throws Exception {
    
    escenario.setTitle("Calcular primos");
    Scene escena=crearEscena();
    escenario.setScene(escena);
    escenario.show();
  }

  private Scene crearEscena() throws NumberFormatException{
     
        Label label=new Label("Introduce un numero: ");
        TextField campoNumero=new TextField();
        TextArea area=new TextArea();
        Button calcular=new Button("Calcular");
        HBox cajaHorizontal=new HBox(label,campoNumero);
        cajaHorizontal.setSpacing(10);
        cajaHorizontal.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox CajaVertical=new VBox(cajaHorizontal,area,calcular);
        CajaVertical.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene escena=new Scene(CajaVertical,400,300);
        
        calcular.setOnAction(e->imprimirNumero(campoNumero, area));
        imprimirNumero(campoNumero,area);
        return escena;
      
  }
  private void imprimirNumero(TextField texto,TextArea area) {
    try {
      int numero=Integer.parseInt(texto.getText());
      int cantidadMostrados;
      int num;
      cantidadMostrados = 1;
      num = 3;
      area.setText(Integer.toString(2));
      
      while (cantidadMostrados < numero) {
        boolean esPrimo = true;
        for (int divisor=3; divisor<=Math.sqrt(num) && esPrimo; divisor+=2) {
          if (num%divisor==0) {
            esPrimo = false;
          }
        }
        if (esPrimo) {
          cantidadMostrados++;
          System.out.println(num);
          area.setText(Integer.toString(num));
        }
        num += 2;
      }
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      area.setText("No es un numero");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Si cada vez que vas a actualizar el `TextArea` haces un `setText`, elimina lo que tuviera y lo sustituye por lo nuevo. O lees, añades y haces `setText` o usas `appendText`.

Comment: He usado appendText y me ha funcionado ya, desconocia la existencia de este metodo.Mucha gracias.